# MATLAB: removing non-unique numbers from a field within a structure

Tags: matlab, field, structure, unique, element

I have a structure in Matlab, each field contains elements with varying numbers of variables. I would like to remove duplicates of numbers that appear within the same field: I know the unique() function and know how to use it to scan through fields one at a time but not an entire field.

I think I want something like:

```
structure(1:length(structure)).field=unique(structure(1:length(structure)).field
```

and get 
original

```
field=[1,2,3] [1,4,5] [2,5,8]
```

to turn into

```
field=[1,2,3] [4,5] [8]
```

Maybe a complicated for loop similar to below (isn't working) which would grab the values from the first element in the field, search through each additional element, and if that value is present set it equal to =[];, and iterate through that way?

```
    for n=1:length(RESULTS)
        for m=1:length(RESULTS(n).Volumes)
            for l=1:length(RESULTS)
                for o=1:length(RESULTS(l).Volumes)
                    if RESULTS(n).Volumes(m)==RESULTS(l).Volumes(o)
                        RESULTS(l).Volumes(o)=[];
                    end               
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick-and-dirty attempt, but you might be able to improve on it. Assume your struct array and field are `sa(:).v`. I'm also assuming that the field contains a 1xn array of numbers, as in your example. First, make a "joint" array with the concatenation of all field values and filter the non-unique values:

```
joint = cell2mat({sa.v});    
[uniqJoint,~,backIdx] = unique(joint);
```

The "uniqJoint" array has also been sorted, but the "backIdx" array contains the indices that, if applied to uniqJoint, will rebuild the original "joint" array. We need to somehow connect those to the original indices (i,j) into the struct array and within the field value `sa(i).v(j)`. To do that, I tried creating an array of the same size as "joint" that contains the indices of the struct that originally had the corresponding element in the "joint" array:

```
saIdx = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) i * ones(1,length(sa(i).v)), ...
                 1:length(sa), 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Then you can edit (or, in my case, copy and modify the copy of) the struct array to set the field to the values that have not appeared before. To do that, I keep a logical array to mark the indices of "backIdx" as "already used", in which case I skip those values when rebuilding the fields of each struct:

```
sb = sa;
used = false(length(backIdx));
for i = 1:length(sa)
  origInd = find(saIdx == i); % Which indices into backIdx correspond to this struct?
  newInd = []; % Which indices will be used?
  for curI = backIdx(origInd)
    if ~used(curI)
      % Mark as used and add to the "to copy" list
      used(curI) = true;
      newInd(end+1) = curI;
    end
  end
  % Rewrite the field with only the indices that were not used before
  sb(i).v = uniqJoint(newInd);
end
```

In the end, the data in `sb(i).v` contains the same numbers as `sa(i).v` without repeats, and removing those that appeared in any previous elements of the struct.